# How to link Delphi with C++?

Tags: c++, delphi, linker, c++builder

#### cpp.cpp

```
extern "C"
char* GetText()
{
  return "Hello, world!";
}
```

#### delphi.dpr

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$LINK 'cpp.obj'}
function _GetText: PChar; cdecl; external;

begin
  WriteLn(_GetText);
end.
```

I can't get this to work, no matter what I try. I tried various calling conventions, playing with underscores. even creating a .c wrapper for the .cpp code (but then the .c wrapper doesn't "see" any .cpp symbols). I'm about to give up and use DLLs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the error you get when you're trying to link the above?

Comment: delphi.dpr(7) Error: E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_GetText'

Comment: The problem is that Delphi's linker doesn't "see" anything declared in C++ code, so I can't refer to C++ symbols from neither Delphi nor C code.

Comment: FWIW, renaming the .cpp file in the example to .c and deleting the first line fixes it, but obviously this won't let me use C++ code.

Comment: Why not use C++ Builder?

Comment: I don't see how using C++ Builder will solve my problem, considering the main application is written in Delphi.

Comment: BCB has certain Delphi interoperability features. IIRC search for "pureclass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run into a limitation of the compiler.

These two articles cover your options in fairly good detail:

- http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html
- http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html